# Searching for column name, search for objects in that column and change the cell content if object is found to zero

Tags: excel, vba

This is the first time i write a question in here so if breach decorum by asking my question I apologize. Long story short, I am currently trying to make a macro in visual basic for Excel. I do science stuff, in this case algae.

But column and row can be dynamic in my data sets, sometimes very large. So what I am trying to make is a macro that will do this.

1. Search for part of/full column name (that is okay).
2. Once it finds the column by name i want it that column to be marked for the next step. Keep in mind that the range of columns and row is dynamic so the algae, chrysochromulina rotalis is not always in column B or E. (having trouble with this. Best i can do is the "step down function multiple times)
3. Once the column is marked I want to search that column for an object (again, easy) like the object <. Now if it finds this object like a cell with "<5" i want it to change the entire cell value to zero. Regardless if it is <5 or <100.

I again apologize if asking my question in this way is a breach of how questions is asked on this site. But if someone can point me in a direction of a good book to solve the problem or can give me some hints so i can learn i will be truly grateful.

```
Sub I_suck_at_VBA()
'
' I_suck_at_VBA Makro
'

    Cells.Find(What:="Chrys", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt _
        :=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:= _
        False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate

    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select

'The next step fails very hard by the way

    Selection.Replace What:="<", Replacement:="0", LookAt:=xlPart, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
        ReplaceFormat:=False

    Range("D24").Select
End Sub
```

example excel sheet [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EtPuH.png)

Comment: change `"<"` to `"<*"`

Comment: So, to be more clear about what you want, you want to loop through columns till you find the name "chrysochromulina rotalis" then loop through the rows of that column looking for "<", then replace the value with 0, correct?

Comment: Thank you Doug. I am very impressed that you just wrote it out of boredom and creativity. I wish i could code like that. To answer the question above. Yes I do want it to find the column with header "example: C. rotalis", search the column for < and change that cell to zero. But I also want to make another code for example "P. polylepis" where I change the cell with "<" to 10. I will also like to learn more about how to do this. By the way, do you have any recommendation for reading material or online learning channels that can help me learn more on coding in VBA.

Answer (score 0):

Here because I was bored I wrote this for you. Because you said your data sets are often larger I figured it was worth rewriting your code to do something where you dont select.activate so much as this will bog down excel if your data sets are huge.

```
Private Sub arraysarefun()
    Dim pickUp As Variant
    Dim cols As Long, rowsC As Long
    cols = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet4").UsedRange.Columns.Count
    rowsC = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet4").UsedRange.rows.Count
    pickUp = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet4").UsedRange
    For j = 1 To cols
        If pickUp(1, j) = "myValue" Then
            For i = 1 To rowsC
                If pickUp(i, j) Like ">*" Then
                    pickUp(i, j) = 0
                End If
            Next i
        End If
    Next j
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet4").Range(ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet4").Cells(1, 1), ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet4").Cells(rowsC, cols)).Value2 = pickUp
End Sub
```

This picks up the sheet into an array then loops through the columns. Once it finds "myValue" it loops through that column's rows to find anything with a > preceding its value. If you need to change what column it loops through try using this (or some variation of it keeping in mind + values go right, - values go left for j, where + values go down and - values go up for i):

```
            If pickUp(i, j+1) Like ">*" Then
                pickUp(i, j+1) = 0
            End If
```